# Find a conformal mapping from $U=\{z:|z|<1\}\smallsetminus[1/2,1)$ to upper half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a conformal mapping from $U=\{z:|z|<1\}\smallsetminus[1/2,1)$ to upper half plane.

My first thought is to send $z\mapsto \sqrt{z}$, which gives the upper half disk plus the real interval $[0,1/\sqrt2]$.

Then taking $z\mapsto\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ gives us the first quadrant plus the real interval $[1,1/(1-1/\sqrt2)]$.

Now squaring gives the upper half plane, plus the interval $[1,1/(1-1/\sqrt2)^2]$. This real interval is what's giving me trouble; I don't know how to get rid of it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\zeta =\phi(z)=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$ maps $U$ to $V=\{\zeta :|\zeta |<1\}\setminus [0,1).$

$\xi=\varphi (\zeta )=\sqrt{\zeta }$ maps $V$ to the upper half-disk $D^+=\{\xi : |\xi|<1, \operatorname{Im} \xi>0\}$.

$w=\psi(\xi)=\left(\frac{1+\xi}{1-\xi}\right)^2$ maps $D^+$ to the upper half plane.

$w=\psi\circ\varphi \circ\phi(z)$ is one you desired.

Comment: Why $w$ maps upper half disk to upper half plane?

Comment: @mnmn1993 - A Mobius map $\eta=\frac{1+\xi }{1-\xi }$ maps $|\xi |<1$ to the right half plane.
For $\xi =x+iy$ with $ x^2+y^2<1$ and $y>0$, 
$$
\eta =\frac{1+x+iy}{1-(x+iy)}=\frac{1-(x^2+y^2)}{(1-x)^2+y^2}+i\frac{2y}{(1-x)^2+y^2}.
$$
So $\operatorname{Re} \eta>0$ and $\operatorname{Im}\eta>0$, which means that $g$ maps the upper half disk $|\xi |<1,\; \operatorname{Im}\xi>0$ to the first quadrant. Therefore $\zeta =\eta^2=\left(\frac{1+\xi }{1-\xi }\right)^2$ maps the upper half disk to the upper half plane.

Comment: @mnmn1993 - Sorry. $\zeta$ should be $w$.